# How to plot directed acyclic lattice graph in R

Tags: r, graph, lattice, igraph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need to plot directed acyclic lattice graph of size m x n, similar as in this picture, but without edges on the contour and without vertexes on the corners:

[image]

Is this possible to do with `graph.lattice` function? If yes, how to set such vertexes' labels (i.e. (x,y) format, not just an  integer number) and remove mentioned edges and vertexes? Moreover, is it possible to plot graph in such position (as in a picture) without using tkplot function and rotating it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by 'without edges on the contour', but here are some points:

- Read `?igraph.plotting` for the complete list of plotting parameters.
- If you don't want the frame on the vertices, set `vertex.frame.color` to the same value as `vertex.color`.
- Use `layout.grid`, see `?layout.grid`.
- Use `vertex.label` to set the labels.
- If you want to omit some edges, then delete them, or set their width to zero or their color to background color.
- If you want to omit some vertices, then attach the coordinates calculated by `layout.grid` as vertex attributes, and then remove the vertices from the graph.

Something like this could work:

```
g <- graph.lattice( c(5,5) )
lay <- layout.grid(g)
V(g)$x <- lay[,1]
V(g)$y <- lay[,2]
V(g)$color <- V(g)$frame.color <- "darkolivegreen"
V(g)$label.color <- "lightgrey"
V(g)$label <- paste(V(g)$x+1, V(g)$y+1, sep=",")
```

To remove the edges, you can select them based on the coordinates of the vertices:

```
torem <- c(E(g)[ V(g)[x==0] %--% V(g)[x==0] ], 
           E(g)[ V(g)[y==0] %--% V(g)[y==0] ], 
           E(g)[ V(g)[x==4] %--% V(g)[x==4] ], 
           E(g)[ V(g)[y==4] %--% V(g)[y==4] ])
g2 <- delete.edges(g, torem)
```

And then remove the vertices and plot:

```
g3 <- delete.vertices(g2, V(g2)[ x %in% c(0,4) & y %in% c(0,4) ])
plot(g3, layout=cbind(V(g3)$x, V(g3)$y))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By 'without edges on the contour' I meant how to remove edges which are on the contour of a grid (grid before deletion of corner vertices), i.e. how to delete edges (2,1)-(3,1), (3,1)-(4,1), (1,2)-(1,3), (1,3)-(1,4), etc.? At that moment I'm using delete.edges function and just name the indexes, but it wouldn't work for large graphs.

Comment: Moreover, is this possible to color "squares" bounded by edges with different colors in this picture? For example, to color area, bounded by (2,2)-(2,3),(2,3)-(3,3), (3,3)-(3,2), (2,2)-(3,2) in one color, and other such area in other color? Can I do that by setting parameter mark.col somehow?

Comment: You can do that with `symbols(squares=..., add=TRUE, inches=FALSE, ...)`. But then you will need to plot this first, and then plot the graph, with `add=TRUE, rescale=FALSE`. Start a new question if you need help.